# Input does not consist of pandas.Series containing only Strings

Tags: python, pandas, string-matching

I am using the string_mathing module of the string_grouper library, to find possible duplications and clients according to their personal data.

The code:

```
base1=pd.DataFrame(base[['Cliente','registro']])
matches = match_strings(base1['registro'], master_id =base1['Cliente'],ignore_index=True, min_similarity = 0.5,regex=r"[,-./]|\s", tfidf_matrix_dtype=np.float32)
```

But I throw the following error:

```
**TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\MXROBL~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1952/2333918413.py in <module>
      2 
      3 # Create all matches:
----> 4 matches = match_strings(base1['registro'], master_id =base1['Cliente'],ignore_index=True, min_similarity = 0.5,regex=r"[,-./]|\s", tfidf_matrix_dtype=np.float32)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\string_grouper\string_grouper.py in match_strings(master, duplicates, **kwargs)
     67     :return: pandas.Dataframe
     68     """
---> 69     string_grouper = StringGrouper(master, duplicates=duplicates, **kwargs).fit()
     70     return string_grouper.get_matches()
     71 
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\string_grouper\string_grouper.py in __init__(self, master, duplicates, **kwargs)
    126         if not StringGrouper._is_series_of_strings(master) or \
    127                 (duplicates is not None and not StringGrouper._is_series_of_strings(duplicates)):
--> 128             raise TypeError('Input does not consist of pandas.Series containing only Strings')
    129 
    130         self._config: StringGrouperConfig = StringGrouperConfig(**kwargs)
TypeError: Input does not consist of pandas.Series containing only Strings**
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: It might be interesting for you to provide example data. So users can answer your question more easily.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Ran into same error today. My dataframe was created from table data. After exhausting my troubleshooting ideas, finally decided to "manually" create the dataframe using the same data, which worked. No more issues. Only have about 12,000 names so not a big deal, but still, no idea what happened.